# Using sed to replace a string with special chars with another string with special characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, quoting, string

I'm trying to automate switching out a bash prompt for another in .bashrc

Original String:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Replacement Strings:

```
IPeth0=$(Adr=$(ifconfig eth0 |grep inet); echo $Adr | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 6- )
PS1='\d \t \[\e[0;31m\]\u@$IPeth0\[\e[0;32m\]:\[\e[0;36m\]\w# \[\e[m\] '
```

One of many poor attempts at writing bash to do so:

```
#!/bin/bash
original="PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '"
replacement="PS1='\d \t \[\e[0;31m\]\u@$IPeth0\[\e[0;32m\]:\[\e[0;36m\]\w# \[\e[m\] '" 
ipvar="IPeth0=$(Adr=$(ifconfig eth0 |grep inet); echo $Adr | awk '{print \$2}' | cut -c 6- )"

cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
sed -e 's/$original/$replacement/g' ~/.bashrc
```

I've tried double escaping all of the characters because I know sed needs '\','/', and '&' escaped. I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

I didn't even bother trying to get the IP line in there right away because I couldn't replace the first line.

If there are any better methods for this type of automation please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of approaches (well, 2½):

- If you’re interested in being able
  to incrementally modify `PS1` settings that follow a general template,

  - Create a file that contains only the `PS1=…` line.
  - Write `sed` commands to edit it, piece by piece; e.g.,

    - `sed -e 's/${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}/\\d \\t /'`
    - `sed -e 's/\\033/\\e/g'`
    - etc.
  - You might find it easier to debug these smaller, simpler commands. 
    When you’ve gotten them all working,
    it should be straightforward to stitch them together.
  - Have you *looked at* the value of `$original`? 
    E.g., have you done
             `printf "%s\n" "$original"`
    ?  Remember, when you say something like

    ```
    "The quick brown fox 'jumps over' the lazy dog."
    ```

    The entire string is in *double* quotes. 
    So when you say

    ```
    "Humpty '$var' Dumpty"
    ```

    The `$var` gets expanded, because it’s in double quotes.

    Now  look at your `original` string:

    ```
    original="PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:…"
    ```

    The `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` gets expanded
    when you make that assignment.  So that’s a problem.
- If you just want to change `PS1` to your new value,
  regardless of what’s already there,
  don’t try to chisel down the statue of the fox
  and then add clay in the hopes of creating a statue of a dog;
  just blow away the existing assignment and replace it,
  using `sed`’s `c` (**c**hange) command,
  which replaces one group of one or more lines
  with another group of one or more lines:

  ```
  sed -e $'/^PS1=/c\
  IPeth0=$(Adr=$(ifconfig eth0 |grep inet); echo $Adr | awk \'{print $2}\' | cut -c 6- )\
  PS1=\'\d \t \[\e[0;31m\]\u@$IPeth0\[\e[0;32m\]:\[\e[0;36m\]\w# \[\e[m\] \''
  ```

  I put the entire `sed` command string into `$'…'`
  so I could use `\'` to get raw `'` characters into the string. 
  If you prefer, you can use the tried and true

  ```
  '$not_a_variable …'"… please don't try to expand those …"'… $not_a_variable'
  ```

  (quote alternation) technique.
- A variant on the above is

  ```
  sed -e $'/^PS1=/{s/^/# /; a\
  IPeth0=$(Adr=$(ifconfig eth0 |grep inet); echo $Adr | awk \'{print $2}\' | cut -c 6- )\
  PS1=\'\d \t \[\e[0;31m\]\u@$IPeth0\[\e[0;32m\]:\[\e[0;36m\]\w# \[\e[m\] \'
  }'
  ```

  which comments out the existing definition (`s/^/# /`)
  and **a**ppends the new lines with the `a` command.